# Can I reuse GRPC connections?

Tags: c#, grpc

Can I reuse a connection by making a field for the channel and client so I can reuse the client over multiple calls or should I create a new client for each call?

```cs
public async Task DoSomething()
{
  var channel = new Channel("endpoint", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
  var client = new Service.ServiceClient(channel);
  // call client
  await channel.ShutdownAsync();
}
```

or

```cs
ctor
{
  _channel = new Channel("endpoint", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
  _client = new Service.ServiceClient(channel);
}
public async Task DoSomething()
{
  // call _client
}
public async Task Dispose()
{
  await _channel.ShutdownAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I reuse GRPC connections?

Short answer is **yes** and you should.

In my opinion, re-use the client. Best practice would be to maintain these connections because they can have an overhead when creating new one's instead of concurrently maintaining the current instance. The only issue I *could* foresee is if you may run into stream limits, which is also limited by how many concurrent streams you can have, but this is very many and probably not be your case.

Comment: I doubt this practice is reusing the "connection", like using TCP/HTTP "keepalive". Nevertheless, it's certainly likely to be a good practice, but it isn't the "connection" you're reusing.